# foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given

Tags: php, laravel

I am quite new to laravel and I have a weird problem with foreach() blade directive.
the problem is when I want to iterate over a collection it throws an error and says:

```
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given
```

but I have printed the collection using print_r() method and it the variable does not hold any string, it hold a collection object.

that is the piece of code that throws the error while reaching the foreach directive:

```
<section class="col-span-8 col-start-5 mt-10 space-y-6">
     {{print_r($post->comments)}}
     @foreach($post->comments as $comment) // here
          <x-post-comment :comment="$comment"></x-post-comment>
     @endforeach
</section>
```

basically, in the above code in the foreach I have a Eloquent relationship and between Post and Comment Models and the relationship works perfectly in tinker, but here it says that it is not a collection or an array. also, I have a post-comment blade component that renders the layout for a commment inside the foreach.

and that is the implementation of the relationship between each post and its comments:

```
 function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

as I mentioned, the above relationship works perfectly, but I don't know what is wrong with it.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check if you have any `@foreach` in `<x-post-comment>` which may be failing

Comment: what type has `$post->comments` ?

Comment: It is not `print_r` but `var_dump` or `dump` what you have to use to see the variable type and content... check that, as it is clearly not an `object` or `array`...

Comment: @Donkarnash bro I don't have any foreach directives in <x-post-comment> blade component.

Comment: @user973254 bro it has a type of:

 object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)

Comment: @matiaslauriti bro I have used var_dump() and gettype() as well, the type of of $post->comments is object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection). 
and this is clearly shows that it is an object.

Comment: If `$post->comments` is a `Collection` `@foreach` shouldn't give this error. Are you sure the error is occurring at `@foreach($post->comments as $comment)` line? Check any other blade views including the partials(if any) as well as master layout to ensure that it's not failing at any other foreach loop

Comment: @Donkarnash brother, I am sure the error happens at this foreach, because when I comment it out, the error will go away instantly. 

and I have doing coding for almost 2 years in Java and Dart (Flutter), so I am not new to programming. however, this is a weird error that I have got.

Comment: Intent is not to question your programming experience rather it is to help trying to figure out possible source of error and get a resolution. In this case it's not logical to get the said error as argument to foreach is of type is `Collection` as you have confirmed. Don't think it would make much difference but try `php artisan view:clear` or `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: @Donkarnash bro I fixed it in other way.

 the problem was inside <x-post-comment> component I was writing @props('comment') instead of @props(['comment'])

 
So, I was missing the square brackets around 'comment'. but the error message was about foreach not props that why I was thinking all about the foreach part. I have wasted several hours on that. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help bro! appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside `<x-post-comment>` component I was writing `@props('comment')` instead of `@props(['comment'])` So, I was missing the square brackets around 'comment'.

The error message was about foreach not props that why I was thinking all about the foreach part.

(answered by @Yassin in the comments)